# Transform if the json has a single object to array in JOLT

Tags: jolt

I have a Json which can have a inner json as an object or array, but i want to transform it as array always even if it has one element.

```
Input Json:

{
"payload": {
    "payloadVersion": "1",
    "settings": [
        {
            "image": "abc",
            "accounts": {
                "accountName": "netflix"
            }
        },
        {
            "image": "abc",
            "accounts": [
                {
                    "accountName": "amazon"
                },
                {
                    "accountName": "disney"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

In the above **accounts** can be a single value or array, but I want it to be always as a array if it comes as single object and if it come as a array then it should be as is.

```
Output Json:

{
"payload": {
    "payloadVersion": "1",
    "settings": [
        {
            "image": "abc",
            "accounts": [
                {
                    "accountName": "netflix"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "image": "abc",
            "accounts": [
                {
                    "accountName": "amazon"
                },
                {
                    "accountName": "disney"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

need help to write a JOLT specification for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "settings": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&3.&2.[&1].&",
            "accounts": {
              "accountName": {
                "@(2,accounts)": "&5.&4.[&3].&2[]"
              },
              "0": {
                "@(2,accounts)": "&5.&4.[&3].&2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you it worked, but only problem is payloadVersion went outside of payload like {
  "payloadVersion" : "1",
  "payload" : {

Comment: I apologize . I fixed this in the spec itself in my response.